# Google forms: Add item to response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

Can I programatically add an item to a form response after the user has submitted it? In this case, I would like to add the `editResponseURL`, so that I have a record of it in my spreadsheet along with the other data.

```
function onSubmit(event){
    var formResponse = event.response;
    var responseURL = formResponse.getEditResponseUrl();

    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

    //Does something like this next line exist?
    itemResponses.add("Response URL", responseURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assume the the current On Form Submit event is the last row in the destination sheet.  So, get the last row in the sheet, get a range of the cell to be updated, and then use the `setValue()` method.

```
function onSubmit(){
  //To do - Get the edit url
  var theLastResponse = code here;
  var theEditUrl = theLastResponse  code for edit URL

  //Get current spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var responsesSheet = ss.getSheetByName('yourSheetNameHere');

  var theLastRow = responsesSheet.getLastRow();
  var columnToAddUrlTo = 9; //Hard code the column if you want
  var cellRangeToSet = responsesSheet.getRange(theLastRow, columnToAddUrlTo).setValue(theEditUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy. This adds to the local array but unfortunately the change does not get carried over into the Spreadsheet responses. The change also appears to only be local. For example if I call `formResponse.getItemResponses()` again, the array is unchanged.

Comment: That's what I meant by "in my spreadsheet along with the other data". Sorry it wasn't more clear.